# How to plot inequalities?

Tags: tikz-3dplot

I want to 3D plot the range of (x,y) given by

g(x,y,t)>=0 and h(x,y,t)>=0 for all t>=0.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The `\fill` command works in 3d just as in 2d. Assuming that you have a bunch of data points, something like `\fill plot file{filename}`should get you started. It does however depend on your function, but in a general case, this is where you would start. Additionally, take a look at the pgf manual, section 13ff describes specifying coordinates. http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Comment: Look at `pgfplots`which can plot in 3d. `tikz-3dplot` is not the right package.

Comment: Please post minimal code reproducing your problem, also known as [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).